# Not able to integrate salesforce mobile sdk in android studio

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce

I am new to salesforce. I have to integrate Salesforce mobile sdk to my android app. 
I am using this lib as mentioned documentation [https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/libs/SalesforceSDK/libs](http://git)

When i add this lib to android project as module in android studio i face following error.

```
/Users/gauravs/AndroidStudioProjects/BsdPoc/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/ui/sfhybrid/SalesforceDroidGapActivity.java
Error:(38, 26) error: cannot find symbol class CordovaWebViewClient
Error:(157, 15) error: cannot find symbol class CordovaWebViewClient
Error:(140, 45) error: cannot find symbol method getSettings()
Error:(156, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(158, 52) error: incompatible types: SalesforceDroidGapActivity cannot be converted to CordovaInterface
/Users/gauravs/AndroidStudioProjects/BsdPoc/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/ui/sfhybrid/SalesforceIceCreamWebViewClient.java
Error:(36, 26) error: cannot find symbol class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
Error:(43, 54) error: cannot find symbol class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
Error:(65, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(70, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(74, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(80, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(83, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(85, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable super
```

I understand Cordova.jar is missing these class but i tried with cordova 1.8 and 2.3 there were more missing class i downloaded cordove 5.0 it reduce missing class but stil above class can any one tell me what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an earlier version of Cordova, I believe anything in 3.x should work. Personally, I had success with version 3.6.3-0.2.13 when used with forcedroid version 3.0.0.